# Invalid column name in c sharp exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```cs
string query = @$"declare @p geog = geog::Point(@lng, @lat, 4326);
                    SELECT v.VehicleId, d.DriverId, v.VehicleNo, g.LogDate FROM tbl_gps_log g INNER join tbl_vehicles v on  v.vehicleid = g.productid
                    left OUTER JOIN tbl_vehicle_driver_assign d on d.VehicleId = v.VehicleId and g.LogDate between d.AssignDate and ISNULL(d.UnAssignDate,'12/31/2099')
                    where v.OrgId = @orgId and Latitude is not null and Longitude is not null and LogDate between @fromDate and @toDate
                    and (g.productid = @productId or @productId = 0)
                    and (d.DriverId = @driverId or @driverId = 0)
                    and @p.STDistance(p) < 250
                    order by { (groupBy == "V" ? "v.VehicleNo" : "d.DriverId") }, g.LogDate ";
```

Comment: does it tell you which column? this sounds like simply an issue with the SQL having *an incorrect column cited*; if you take the SQL over to SSMS and run it there: does it work?

Comment: ex: invalid column p

Comment: `@p.STDistance(p)` - do you have a column called `p`? It sounds like the answer is no, but *only you have access to your table definitions currently*. If not, what did you *expect* that line to do?

Comment: I *guess* the that expression should be `@p.STDistance(geog::Point(Longitude, Latitude, 4326)) < 250` ?

Comment: Thanks. It got fixed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever
 I'm new to programming, how do I learn to debug this kind of errors?

Comment: `ISNULL(d.UnAssignDate,'12/31/2099')` may be better as `ISNULL(d.UnAssignDate,'20991231')` to avoid issues with different date formats.

Comment: @mjwills or just `73048` :) SQL Server `datetime` is a numerical value where the integer part is "days since 1900"

Comment: How to modify this to make it run in SQL server

Comment: @MarcGravell True - although perhaps slightly harder to understand. :)

Comment: @GopalP re "How to modify this to make it run in SQL server" - everything we've said has been talking about SQL Server; there is nothing to modify